# Manipulating large amounts of pixels on iOS

Tags: ios, performance, ios5, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I need to move large amounts of pixels on the screen on an iOS device. What is the most efficient way of doing this?

So far I'm using `glTexSubImage2D()`, but I wonder if this can be done any faster. I noticed that OpenGL ES 2.0 does not support pixel buffers, but there seems to be a pixel buffer used by Core Video. Can I use that? Or maybe there's an Apple extension for OpenGL that could help me achieve something similar (I think saw a very vague mention about a client storage extension in one of the WWDC 2012 videos, but I can't find any documentation about it)? Any other way that I can speed this up?

My main concern is that `glTexSubImage2D()` copies all the pixels that I send. Ideally, I'd like to skip this step of copying the data, since I already have it prepared...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client storage extension you're probably thinking of is `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage`; a full tutorial is [here](http://allmybrain.com/2011/12/08/rendering-to-a-texture-with-ios-5-texture-cache-api/). That's definitely going to be the fastest way to get data to the GPU.

Frustratingly the only mention I can find of it in Apple's documentation is the [iOS 4.3 to 5.0 API Differences](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/iOS50APIDiff/) document — do a quick search for `CVOpenGLESTextureCache.h`.